# How to Use order by and group by together / coalesce and distinct together?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, coalesce

I got a query like this

```
 select  tm.id as id,
    mf.function_name as function_role,
  e.name as NAME
  from employee e 
  join team_members tm on e.emp_id=tm.emp_id
  join mem_function mf on mf.function_id = tm.function_id
  order by mf.position
```

For  a particular ID the result set is

```
 ID | Function_Role | Name
  1    manager        Apple
  1    Engineer       Apple
  1    Engineer 2     Orange
```

Now I want my result to be to

```
   1    Manager       Apple
   1    Engineer2     Orange
```

Is there a way to get this without using a select inside a select?

I tried using groupby it throws an error saying "Not a group by expression"
I also tried select distinct it throws an error "Not a SELECTed expression"

Note:I need that order by to sort and display according to the position

Comment: I don't understand why 1,engineer,apple is dropped,what's the logic for the result you want?

Comment: @P.Salmon I want NAME column to be unique and Function_Role to be sorted based on the position(mf.position)

Comment: I'm not going to reverse engineer your tables but if you would like to add sample data as text to the question or sqlfiddle I would be happy to look again.